# Do I have a 32-bit or 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows-7

I have a Dell Inspiron 3521 laptop, it's 1 year old. How can I tell if it's 32-bit or 64-bit? On Dell's website, it is listed as 64-bit, but in the System Information dialog box it displays the system type as `x86` which indicates that it's 32-bit.

Comment: Windows Logo Key + R > "winver". This used to show the type of OS on older versions of Windows; it no longer does this in 8.1, but it should work in Windows 7 if I remember correctly.

Comment: @user2428118, I have Windows 7 Pro x64, and 'winver' doesn't show 32-bit or 64-bit.  It does give the long version number, but that's it.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I'm probably confusing it with something else, then.

Answer (score 6):

I would go with what the System page on the control panel shows

This is an example of what you should see:

[image]

You can find this by going to the file explorer and right clicking on This PC

[image]

or on the control panel enter this

> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System

There is the possibility that you are using 32 Bit OS when your system is capable of using 64bit

Comment: Also, WinKey+Pause will open the System window if you have a keyboard with a Pause key (not the media play/pause button - the one that says "Pause"...)

Comment: it's the one labeled "pause/break"

Answer (score 6):

Another way to checking whether you are running a 32- or 64-bit Windows OS is to look for the folders `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)`. If you have both, you are running on a 64-bit OS. If you only have the former, then you are running on a 32-bit OS.

Comment: This answers "How can I tell if Windows is 32 or 64 bit", but doesn't show if his "system" is 64 bit.  The OP is running 32-bit windows on a 64-bit processor.

Answer (score 4):

You have a 32bit version of windows installed on 64bit hardware.

Comment: Source? Can you [edit] to expand a bit? This is a very low quality answer that would fail to help future visitors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>pause</kbd> it will bring you to
`Control Panel`>`All  Control Panel Items`>`System`.

Here under **System Type** you will find either **32 or 64-bit**.

As backup of course you can select Control Panel from Start menu and Select System from there.